# Change color of "highlight" in ContextualActionMode for different theme

Tags: android, textview, android-actionmode, mobile-development

As a short explanation: We are developing an Android App for the university. On the first screen is a list. This list is made by a ListView containing lots of TextViews. The following code is in our CustomListAdapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);//let the adapter handle setting up the row views
        v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        if (mSelection.get(position) != null) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
        }

        return v;
    }
```

I found out, that the line inside the if statement:   `v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));`  sets the color for the selected items of our list. Is there a way to change this color for different themes? So that it is for example like this (blue) in one theme, but orange or something in a diferent theme.

I tried it with different solutions like that one:

```
<style name="BlackTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
</style>
```

for `android:background`I used multiple different attributes, but none of them worked until now.

I also tried setting 
 `v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));` to 
 `v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedItem));`,  this color is set as the following:
`<color name="selectedItem">?attr/selectableItemBackground</color>`
and my style containes the line `<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>`.  This also does not work, because it throws an error of type "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0054 type #0x2 is not valid"

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try using it android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: I am not really sure where you want me to use that. In the .xml for the TextView? Or somewhere in the styles.xml. And how exactly?

Comment: it can be added to xml or programmtically you can set this. What is does is that it used the android attr for selectableBackground and if your app theme changes, it will also changes according to the them.

Comment: I added this line now to my `custom_list.xml` (this file contains the TextViews from my list). Nothing changed.
Then I added the line `<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>` to my style definition, and now the TextViews always had the color orange, not just when selected..